# Browser render svg <clipPath> to <clippath>

Tags: javascript, html, svg, web, browser

Some browsers force render the svg tag form **clipPath** to lower case **clippath**. So the clipPath doesn't work.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Btw, the ua of my browser is *Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; zh-CN; ONEPLUS A3000 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/10.8.5.689 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30*

Thanks.

Comment: Download the webkit source code and write a bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create your element with the good namespace:

```
var clipPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","clipPath");
```

Comment: @RobertLongson maybe you could point to a bug report ? It's not clear at all what you are talking about, just like that.

Comment: @Kaiido The webkit bug on this was fixed. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46800 it was never a namespace problem, the webkit parser/serialiser was simply broken but fortunately not any more. I've voted to close the question as no longer reproducable.